# find alphabets and special characters in phone number field using an SQL query

Tags: postgresql

I need to test if my phone number column values have any alphabets and special characters in the filed.
do you know something that can help?

SELECT distinct phone FROM table WHERE phone= PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%')
error i got:
Function patindex(unknown) doesnot exist.you might need to add explicit type casts.

table 
name    phone
 ss    (111)222-4444 
 xx    (222)(333)4444 
 yy    223$36&888 
 zz    6738^3!@77 .ext 
 aa    777888stop

output (i would like to see this in my output) 
name   phone 
yy     223$36&888 
zz     6738^3!@77 .ext 
aa     777888stop 
my purpose of this is... i should clean up the phone number which has special characters and alphabets.
There are too many invalid chars, so I would like to test really for only numbers allowed.

Comment: I am very new to this so trying to learn .select phone from table
where phone  like '%[a-z]%'

Comment: When i used patindex it is giving me error: function patindex(unknown) does not exist. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Please add the entire query (queries) you tried, their output, the expected output, and any error messages to your question.

Comment: Perhaps just strip out any non-numeric characters and dump anything not 10 characters? Wouldn't that satisfy your requirements? Something like: `WHERE Length(RegExp_Replace(teleField, '[^0-9]+', '', 'g'))=10;`

Comment: SELECT distinct phone FROM table
WHERE    phone= PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%')
error i got: Function patindex(unknown) doesnot exist. you mifht need to add explicit type casts

table
name         phone
ss  (111)222-4444
xx  (222)(333)4444
yy  223$36&888
zz  6738^3!@77 .ext
aa   777888stop

output (i would like to see this in my output)
name        phone
yy  223$36&888
zz  6738^3!@77 .ext
aa   777888stop

my purpose of this is... i should  clean up the phone number which has special  characters and alphabets.

Comment: `patindex()` is a Microsoft SQL server function. [Check out Postgres documentation on pattern matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html). Something like `phone SIMILAR TO '%[^0-9]%'` would be the equivalent.

Comment: Thank you Jnevill for the link.I would like to see my results the other way.with phone SIMILAR TO'%[^0-9]%' .I mean to say i want to see the output where phone not similar to ' %[^0-9]%'

Comment: Please edit your question to add what you posted as a comment to the question body

Comment: @e4c5 :  edited the question. Your help is much appreciated .